# Any reason to not use R.id.<id_name> as an identifier in my code?

Tags: android

Is there any reason to not use the R.id.<id_name> as a const in my code?

For example, in my ids.xml file I have:

```
<item name="status_running" type="id"/>
<item name="status_finished" type="id"/>
<item name="status_error" type="id"/>
```

which allows me to do things like:

```
switch (status) {
    case R.id.status_running:
         mProgressTextView.setText("Running");
         break;
    case R.id.status_finished:
         mProgressTextView.setText("Finished");
         setNextSyncTime();
         break;
    case R.id.status_error:
         mProgressTextView.setText("Error: " + intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
         break;
    default:
         break;
}
```

Any reason to not use R.id values like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ids like that seems reasonable. The only issue with your code sample might be the recent changes in the android build system. Resource ids in library projects are no longer constants and can't be used in switch statements.

This would only affect you if this code was going to be part of a library project, something to consider at least.

See the blog post [Changes to Library projects in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html) for full details.

Comment: Ah yes - I knew I'd read something about them not being constants somwhere.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access name value as id... You should set a value for id.

Since, you are using a item list (I presume), you should access this in a different way.

Comment: No - this is independent of any UI.  the ID is an int value in the R.java file, and I'm using this int value as an identifier in my code.  I want to know if there's any reason I'm not aware of why I shouldn't do this, instead of writing code like `final static int something = 0x4;`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't store it in the database it's just an constant int like any else. But if you'll store this value (like file or db) you can run into problems since AFAIK id values may change between builds.